# update query for Mongodb in yii

Tags: php, mongodb, yii-extensions, yii

How can I update based on `_id` in mongodb for YII?
What I tried is

```
    $model= new MongoUrls();
      $criteria = new EMongoCriteria;
      $criteria->userid('==', $userid);
      $criteria->screenshot_path('!=', null);
      $criteria->screenshot_uploaded('!=', 1);
      $availablescreenshots=$model-> findAll($criteria);

      if(count($availablescreenshots)>0){
        foreach($availablescreenshots as $obj1){
             $path_parts = pathinfo($obj1->screenshot_path);

             if($social->upload($obj1->screenshot_path, 'test',$path_parts['basename']))          {

     $model->updateAll(array('_id'=>$obj1->_id  ), array('screenshot_uploaded'=>1)  );

} 
                            }

                        }
```

But it shows an error `"The EMongoDocument cannot be updated because it is new."` in Yii .

I want to update a document where `_id` matches same value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method worked for me was

```
$modifier = new EMongoModifier();
$modifier->addModifier('screenshot_uploaded', 'set', '1');
$criteria = new EMongoCriteria();
$criteria->addCond('_id','==', $obj1->_id   );           
$model->updateAll($modifier,$criteria   );
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct in assuming the extension you are using you actually want `$model->updateAll()` since `update()` relates to updating the current active record not to running a general query. It is a bit confusing but it is the way Yii works.

Comment: I think my code also has error in assigning _id . $obj1->_id   has the following value :[_id] => MongoId Object
        (
            [$id] => 51bc570fd39c2c124bda71db
        )
So am I right in array("_id"=>$obj1->_id) ?

Comment: @Zubin If the `_id` of your object is an array and not a `MongoId` object then you have another problem as well, seems like you have an error somewhere before hand that cuases the `_id` of the model to be an array

Comment: I have edited my code so that a more clear understanding can be got about what I have done @Sammaye

Comment: @Zubin Hmm that should work since you are just reading straight form the database, this might be a bug

Answer (score 1):

As [yii mongosuite docs states](http://canni.github.io/YiiMongoDbSuite/xhtml/advanced.partial-batch-update.html), updateAll is a bit different in use than usual update. Also, you are using updateAll in loop and as condition you pass single id which not really makes sense. With updateAll you could use criteria to update models. Here you should use partial update like that:

```
// _id is already set because it comes from db
$obj1->screenshot_uploaded = 1;
// First param to set fields which should be updated
// Set second param to true, to make partial update
$obj1->update(array('screenshot_uploaded'), true);
```